# Show that the market is arbitrage free if $a < S_0^1(1+r)< b$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, finance

**Exercise :**

> We consider a market of one period $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb P, S^0, S^1)$, where the sample space $\Omega$ has a finite number of elements and the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$. Furthermore, with $S^0$ we symbolize the  zero risk asset with initial value $S_0^0=1$ at the time $t=0$ and interest rate $r>-1$ (which means $S_1^0 = 1+r$). With $S^1$ we symbolize an asset with risk with initial value $S_0^1 >0$ at the time $t=0$ and with value $S_1^1$ at the time $t=1$ which is a random variable.
>
> Let $\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\}]>0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. We define :
> $$a:=\min S_1^1(\omega) \quad \text{and} \quad b:=\max S_1^1(\omega)$$
> and we assume that $0<a<b$. Show that the market is arbitrage-free **if and only if** it is :
> $$a<S_0^1(1+r)<b$$

A value process is defined as :

$$V_t = V_t^\bar{\xi} = \bar{\xi}\cdot \bar{S}_t = \sum_{i=0}^d \xi_t^i\cdot \bar{S}_t^i, \quad t \in \{0,1\}$$

where $\xi = (\xi^0, \xi) \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$ is an investment strategy where the number $\xi^i$ is equal to the number of pieces from the security $S^i$ which are contained in the portfolio at the time period $[0,1], i \in \{0,1,\dots,d\}$.

If a market has arbitrage, then the following hold. In case they do not, the market is arbitrage free.

$$V_0 \leq 0, \quad \mathbb P(V1 \geq 0) = 1, \quad \mathbb P(V_1 > 0) > 0$$

**Question :** How would one proceed to proving this using the mathematical definition of arbitrage by constructing a certain strategy ?

Comment: Maybe you should also mention the definition of an arbitrage-free market.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your answer you proved the contrapositive and, hence, the forward implication that no arbitrage implies $a < S_0^1(1+r) < b$.

To prove the converse we assume that $a < S_0^1(1+r) < b$ and show that there can be no possible arbitrage.  A potential arbitrage opportunity arises either from a  portfolio that is short the risk-free asset and long the risky asset (with weights appropriately scaled) where

$$\tag{1}V_0 = \xi S_0^0 + S_0^1 \leqslant 0, \\ \implies \xi \leqslant - \frac{S_0^1}{S_0^0},$$

or a portfolio that long the risk-free asset and short the risky asset where

$$\tag{2}V_0 = S_0^0 + \xi S_0^1 \leqslant 0, \\ \implies \xi \leqslant - \frac{S_0^0}{S_0^1}$$

It then follows that there can be no arbitrage if in either case there exists at least one  future state $\omega$ with non-zero probability such that $V_1(\omega) < 0$.  Under the given assumptions the risky asset attains nonnegative minimum  and maximum values $a = S_1^1(\omega_{min})$ and $b= S_1^1(\omega_{max})$, respectively, where $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_{min}\}) > 0 $ and $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_{max}\}) > 0 $.

Thus, in case (1)

$$\min V_1(\omega) =  \xi S_0^0(1+r) + S_1^1(\omega_{min}) = \xi S_0^0(1+r) + a \\\leqslant -\frac{S_0^1}{S_0^0} S_0^0(1+r)+a  = -S_0^1(1+r) + a  < 0,$$

and in case (2)

$$\min V_1(\omega) = S_0^0(1+r) + \xi S_1^1(\omega_{min}) =  S_0^0(1+r) + \xi b \\\leqslant S_0^0(1+r) - \frac{S_0^0}{S_0^1}b  = \frac{S_0^0}{S_0^1}\left(S_0^1(1+r) - b\right)  < 0$$

Therefore, it is impossible to construct a portfolio such that $V_0 \leqslant 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(V_1 \geqslant  0) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Note :** The following answer was provided by Daneel Olivaw from a post regarding a similar question of mine for finance mathematics at Quantitive Finace Stack exchange : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42637/equivalent-martingale-measure-exists-if-and-only-if-a-s-011r-b . The user Daneel Olivaw providing a hint and a semi-complete answer made me realise that my martingale approach was too complicated and something more practical regarding arbitrage was needed, thus he yielded the elaboration above, which proves the one "side" of the statement.

**Answer of Daneel Olivaw using the arbitrage approach :**

Assume that:

$$ S_0^1(1+r)\leq a,b $$

Arbitrage for a portfolio $V_t$ is defined as:

$$V_0\leq0, \quad P(V_1\geq0)=1, \quad P(V_1>0)>0$$

Consider borrowing at rate $r$ to buy the risky asset such that $V_0=0$. Then, assuming $a\not= b$:

$$\begin{align}
\min_{\omega}V_1(\omega)=a-S_0^1(1+r)\geq 0
\\
\max_{\omega}V_1(\omega)=b-S_0^1(1+r)> 0
\end{align}$$

Thus there is arbitrage. The same argument can be made if $S_0^1(1+r)\geq a,b$ but in this case the risky asset is shorted and the money is lent at a rate $r$. Hence to prevent arbitrage the market has to enforce the following constraint:

$$ a< S_0^1(1+r)< b$$

The inequality does not necessarily need to be strict, we can equivalently have:

$$ a\leq S_0^1(1+r)\leq b$$

Comment: This is the answer that was given to you in your cross-posted question on Quant SE - https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42637. At the very minimum, disclose that it is not your's and close the cross-posted question once you received an answer.

Comment: Sharp as always @LocalVolatility

Comment: This question was posted as a mathematical finance problemon quantitive stack exchange with clear effort shown in my martingale approach. The answer provided helped me understand and I re-posted it here as part of my un-answered question, which yielded a complete answer understanding the converse part of the inequality. The question here was broadly stated and did not include my martingale approach, rather than simply stating the exercise and definition of arbitrage, seeking for a different approach. Also, proper attribution was added in an elaborating note of mine. Thanks for the heads up.